# How to display all lines in file where last field is one digit

Tags: bash, unix

Could someone please help me out with question.
Display all of the lines in the file where the last field is one digit long.
Search for ',' before the field, then use a character class to make sure
it's one digit, and anchor it to the end of the line to make sure it's the
last field.

I have tried :

```
grep ",[0-9]{1}$" inventory

grep ",[.]{1)$" inventory

grep ",[/d]$" inventory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
grep ',[0-9]$' inventory
```

This will work also:

```
grep  ',[[:digit:]]$' inventory
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep ',[0-9]$' inventory
```

You don't need the `{1}` quantifier, since that's the normal meaning of any unquantified regular expression.

`grep` uses basic regular expressions, and doesn't support `\d` to represent digits, so you have to use `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to use:

```
grep ',[0-9]$' inventory
```

You could make the first work with the `-E` option, but the repetition count seems like overkill:

```
grep -E ',[0-9]{1}$' inventory
```

The second is unrescuable because of the mismatch between `{` and `)`, and the `[.]` only matches a dot at the end of the line after the comma.

The last would work if your `grep` supports `-P` (Perl) and you fix the regex:

```
grep -P ',\d$' inventory
```

You don't need the explicit character class brackets because `\d` is already the 'digits' character class.  OTOH, it works OK if you use `,[\d]$`.  The backslash is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

1. Grep uses basic regular expressions (BREs), so you need to escape the `{}`.
2. Since you want exactly one, you don't need `{1}` at all.
3. `[.]` removes the special meaning of `.`, only matching a literal period.
4. `[/d]` (1) digits are `\d`; (2) this matches `/` or `d`, `[\d]` would match `\` or `d`.

You want `,[0-9]$`.